# Remove Bootstrap from bootstrap UI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there a way to find out which customize things I need for **Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel** element from **Bootstrap css**? I know the way of check each bootstrap of each class and tag is inside carousel, but maybe there is a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should only use whatever Bootstrap's carousel component does (if not - please [submit an issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues)).

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js), it only uses templates defined in

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/carousel/carousel.html

and

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/carousel/slide.html